# How can I exclude unnecessary floating number from a match of floating numbers in a single line string

Tags: regex, perl, string-matching

I a newbie in Perl. I just want to ask how can I exclude unnecessary floating numbers in the search list using regex.

I have this sample part of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $teststring = "delay PADI_DEL,del:0.352, 0.352, 0.376, 0.376 PIO PAD PADDI (PADDI:PADDI IOBUF:::IO_TYPE=SUBLVDS,BANK_VCCIO=2.5); pio_INR_drt";

$teststring =~ s/[^\d.\s]//g;
print "$teststring\n";
```

I expect an output like this:

```
0.352 0.352 0.376 0.376
```

The extraction is right but I get unneccessary number after the last floating number I sought. The actual output using my code is like this:

```
0.352 0.352 0.376 0.376      2.5
```

How will I modify my regex such that it will not detect the "2.5" unnecessary floating number.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where is `2.5` coming from? Your string has `3.3` near the end of it.

Comment: 2.5 comes from later part of $teststring
    ...IO_TYPE=SUBLVDS,BANK_VCCIO=2.5....

Comment: At the time I wrote my comment, the later part of `$teststring` was `BANK_VCCIO=3.3`. @ikegami edited the question to correct this.

Comment: i think I have overlooked that. Sorry for the mistake :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input format is rigid, directly grabbing the floats can be done like [this](http://ideone.com/Hhon45)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $teststring = "delay PADI_DEL,del:0.352, 0.352, 0.376, 0.376 PIO PAD PADDI (PADDI:PADDI IOBUF:::IO_TYPE=SUBLVDS,BANK_VCCIO=3.3); pio_INR_drt";

$teststring =~ s/(0\.\d+).*(0\.\d+).*(0\.\d+).*(0\.\d+)//g;
print "$1 $2 $3 $4\n";
```

This searches for 4 floats in the 0.XXX format.

Comment: Thanks for this code. Actually the code that you suggest makes my coding easier since after I detect the floating numbers, I have a plan of assigning each floating number to an array element.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
my @nums = $teststring =~ /[\d.]+/g;
pop @nums;
print "@nums\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can strip of the thing within parents first, (and preceding white-space last):

```
$teststring =~ s/\([^)]*\)//;
$teststring =~ s/[^\d.\s]//g;
$teststring =~ s/^\s*//;
```

And the same idea with an array to store the numbers:

```
$teststring =~ s/\([^)]*\).*$//;
my @v = ($teststring =~ /\d+\.\d+/g);
print join (" ", @v), "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

If your floats are always 5 character long (4 numbers and a dot), this regex'll do the trick:

```
s/[\d.]{5}//g;
```

Comment: He wants to keep the numbers, not remove them.